# Selecting from two tables using oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables namely history and errorlist.
History contains records of a transaction with details. One of these is the errorcode. Namely errorlist table contains list of error  codes and description. Now i want to select the result from two tables showing the number of times a distinct error code occurred from the history table and the relevant error description for the same errorcode from errorlist table. Please help.

Comment: select count(*) as error_count, c.errorno, e.errordesc from hist c inner join errorlist eon c.errorno = e.errorcode group by c.errorno

Comment: but this does not work

Comment: not a group by expression

Comment: Whatever is in the `SELECT` clause and not as an aggregate function (count, sum, max etc) should be in the `GROUP BY` clause http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/21367/2

Comment: yes i got that. so how should i solve this problem?

Comment: One of the worst questions I've seen.

Comment: can anyone really help?

Comment: got it.. select c.CT_ERRORNO,e.EP_ERRORDESC, count(*) from ERR_LIST e, TRAN_HIST_V c where E.EP_ERRORCODE = C.CT_ERRORNO group by c.CT_ERRORNO,e.EP_ERRORDESC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want an inner join on the two tables:

```
select errorcode, errordescription, count(*)
from error, history
where history.errorcode = error.code
group by history.errorcode, history.errordescription
```

EDIT:

Assuming the error code is unique on the error table, and using the field names that you've provided:

```
select h.errorcode, count(*) as count
from history h
group by h.errorcode
```

If you need the description, too then you may need to include a subquery:

```
select z.errorcode, (select errordesc from error where errorcode = z.errorcode), z.count
from (
 select h.errorcode, count(*) as count
 from history h
 group by h.errorcode
) z
```

Comment: i want to have the error description also for corresponding error code displayed in the same resultset

Comment: it should be like errorcount, errorcode, errordescription

Comment: the error description column is present in error table.

Comment: Okay - you haven't supplied any details of the tables, so this is something of a guess.  This should at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: history >> id, detail, errorcode, result

Comment: error >> errorcode, errordesc

Comment: Is the error code unique in the error table?

Comment: select c.CT_ERRORNO,e.EP_ERRORDESC, count(*)
from ERR_LIST e, TRAN_HIST_V c
where E.EP_ERRORCODE = C.CT_ERRORNO
group by c.CT_ERRORNO,e.EP_ERRORDESC